# Turn on mic only when key is pressed like a global push to talk (windows 10)

Tags: windows-10

Is there a built in way in windows 10 to have the Mic off until I press a designated key?

If not, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no built in way, default to Windows, to control your mic with a single key.

There are plenty of software options that add this feature, some may even do it globally, system wide.

I'd recommend using a mature tool such as AutoHotKey, which has sound functions such as controlling volume. Turning the mic volume all the way down is the same as turning it off: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundSet.htm

Comment: This worked. I googled a bit and was able to make a push to toggle mic script with AutoHotKey, thank you. I will accept this answer, but I will post the ahk script in another answer in case it helps someone else solve it more quickly.

Answer (score 2):

These are the scripts I used to toggle the Mic using AutoHotKey:
Based on [this post on their forums](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=15509&p=275410)

pushtotalk.ahk

```
#include togglemic.ahk
$~ctrl:: ; read docs to replace this for your preferred hotkey
    ToggleMic()
    keyWait, ctrl
    ToggleMic()
return
```

togglemic.ahk

```
ToggleMic(){
; 3 is my mic id number, run findmicid.ahk to find yours and replace 3 for your id
SoundSet, +1, MASTER, mute,3 
SoundGet, master_mute, , mute, 3

; uncomment bellow to show tooltips
; ToolTip, Mute %master_mute% 
; SetTimer, RemoveToolTip, 1000
; return

; RemoveToolTip:
; SetTimer, RemoveToolTip, Off
; ToolTip
; return
}
```

findmicid.ahk

```
SetBatchLines -1
SplashTextOn,,, Gathering Soundcard Info...

; Most of the pure numbers below probably don't exist in any mixer, but they're queried for completeness.
; The numbers correspond to the following items (in order): CUSTOM, BOOLEANMETER, SIGNEDMETER, PEAKMETER,
; UNSIGNEDMETER, BOOLEAN, BUTTON, DECIBELS, SIGNED, UNSIGNED, PERCENT, SLIDER, FADER, SINGLESELECT, MUX,
; MULTIPLESELECT, MIXER, MICROTIME, MILLITIME
ControlTypes = VOLUME,ONOFF,MUTE,MONO,LOUDNESS,STEREOENH,BASSBOOST,PAN,QSOUNDPAN,BASS,TREBLE,EQUALIZER,0x00000000, 0x10010000,0x10020000,0x10020001,0x10030000,0x20010000,0x21010000,0x30040000,0x30020000,0x30030000,0x30050000,0x40020000,0x50030000,0x70010000,0x70010001,0x71010000,0x71010001,0x60030000,0x61030000

ComponentTypes = MASTER,HEADPHONES,DIGITAL,LINE,MICROPHONE,SYNTH,CD,TELEPHONE,PCSPEAKER,WAVE,AUX,ANALOG,N/A

; Create a ListView and prepare for the main loop:
Gui, Add, Listview, w400 h400 vMyListView, Component Type|Control Type|Setting|Mixer
LV_ModifyCol(4, "Integer")
SetFormat, Float, 0.2  ; Limit number of decimal places in percentages to two.

Loop  ; For each mixer number that exists in the system, query its capabilities.
{
    CurrMixer := A_Index
    SoundGet, Setting,,, %CurrMixer%
    if ErrorLevel = Can't Open Specified Mixer  ; Any error other than this indicates that the mixer exists.
        break

    ; For each component type that exists in this mixer, query its instances and control types:
    Loop, parse, ComponentTypes, `,
    {
        CurrComponent := A_LoopField
        ; First check if this component type even exists in the mixer:
        SoundGet, Setting, %CurrComponent%,, %CurrMixer%
        if ErrorLevel = Mixer Doesn't Support This Component Type
            continue  ; Start a new iteration to move on to the next component type.
        Loop  ; For each instance of this component type, query its control types.
        {
            CurrInstance := A_Index
            ; First check if this instance of this instance even exists in the mixer:
            SoundGet, Setting, %CurrComponent%:%CurrInstance%,, %CurrMixer%
            ; Checking for both of the following errors allows this script to run on older versions:
            if ErrorLevel in Mixer Doesn't Have That Many of That Component Type,Invalid Control Type or Component Type
                break  ; No more instances of this component type.
            ; Get the current setting of each control type that exists in this instance of this component:
            Loop, parse, ControlTypes, `,
            {
                CurrControl := A_LoopField
                SoundGet, Setting, %CurrComponent%:%CurrInstance%, %CurrControl%, %CurrMixer%
                ; Checking for both of the following errors allows this script to run on older versions:
                if ErrorLevel in Component Doesn't Support This Control Type,Invalid Control Type or Component Type
                    continue
                if ErrorLevel  ; Some other error, which is unexpected so show it in the results.
                    Setting := ErrorLevel
                ComponentString := CurrComponent
                if CurrInstance > 1
                    ComponentString = %ComponentString%:%CurrInstance%
                LV_Add("", ComponentString, CurrControl, Setting, CurrMixer)
            }  ; For each control type.
        }  ; For each component instance.
    }  ; For each component type.
}  ; For each mixer.

Loop % LV_GetCount("Col")  ; Auto-size each column to fit its contents.
    LV_ModifyCol(A_Index, "AutoHdr")

SplashTextOff
Gui, Show
return

GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

- So you first change your mic volume to an arbitrary number easy to
  recognize, then run findmicid.ahk, your id will be next to the
  arbitrary mic volume you just set.
- Set your mic id in togglemic.ahk
- Change the hotkey in pushtotalk.ahk, run it.

That should be it, hope it helps someone looking for the same functionality.